# Python and Semaphores

Tags: python

I am learning about parallelism and Concurrency. My assignment is to quote "This assignment will contain two threaded classes. A Factory will create cars and a Dealership will retrieve them to be sold. There is a limit on the number of cars that a dealership can handle at a time. This is the MAX_QUEUE_SIZE variable. Therefore, if the dealership is full of cars, the Factory must wait to produce cars until some cars are sold." I am struggling with Semaphore's

```
class Factory(threading.Thread):
""" This is a factory.  It will create cars and place them on the car queue """

def __init__(self, qu, empty, full):
    # TODO, you need to add arguments that will pass all of data that 1 factory needs
    # to create cars and to place them in a queue.
    super().__init__()
    self.queue = qu
    self.empty = empty
    self.full = full

def run(self):
    
    self.full.acquire()
    self.empty.acquire()
    
    for i in range(CARS_TO_PRODUCE):
        # TODO Add you code here
        """
        create a car
        place the car on the queue
        signal the dealer that there is a car on the queue
       """
        car = Car()
        self.queue.put(car)
        # time.sleep(1)
        self.empty.release()
        # time.sleep(1)
        self.full.release()
        # time.sleep(random.random() / (SLEEP_REDUCE_FACTOR))
        
    # return self.queue.size()
    # signal the dealer that there there are not more cars

def main():
    log = Log(show_terminal=True)

    # TODO Create semaphore(s)
    empty = threading.Semaphore(10)
    full = threading.Semaphore(0)
    # TODO Create queue251 
    q = Queue251()
    # TODO Create lock(s) ?


    # This tracks the length of the car queue during receiving cars by the dealership
    # i.e., update this list each time the dealer receives a car
    queue_stats = [0] * MAX_QUEUE_SIZE

    # TODO create your one factory
    factory = Factory(q, empty, full)
    dealer = Dealer(q, empty, full)
    # TODO create your one dealership

    log.start_timer()

    # TODO Start factory and dealership
    # empty.acquire()
    # full.acquire()
    factory.start()
    dealer.start()
    # TODO Wait for factory and dealership to complete
    factory.join()
    dealer.join()
    # empty.release()
    # full.acquire()
    log.stop_timer(f'All {sum(queue_stats)} have been created')

    xaxis = [i for i in range(1, MAX_QUEUE_SIZE + 1)]
    plot = Plots()
    plot.bar(xaxis, queue_stats, title=f'{sum(queue_stats)} Produced: Count VS Queue Size', x_label='Queue Size', y_label='Count')



if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

This is the main function and one other function. I talked with one of my colleagues and he said I need to stagger the Semaphores. I would like an explanation rather than a syntax solution seeing as the point to the assignment is to figure out the solution. My understanding of Semaphores is they are a lock except they let more than one thread at a time through. Max_queue_size is 10.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for an explanation and not just a solution, but your code contains a lot of stuff that isn't really required for a solution, while it is missing half of the solution and has some odd choices (where's the Dealership? Why are there two semaphores?). Also, it has indentation problems.

Here's a very straightforward solution:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Semaphore


class Factory(Thread):
    def __init__(self, cars_to_produce, semaphore):
        super().__init__()
        self.cars_to_produce = cars_to_produce
        self.semaphore = semaphore

    def run(self) -> None:
        while self.cars_to_produce:
            self.semaphore.acquire()
            self.cars_to_produce -= 1
            print('Factory: produced a car', flush=True)


class Dealership(Thread):
    def __init__(self, semaphore):
        super().__init__()
        self.semaphore = semaphore

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            if randint(0, 1) == 0:
                self.semaphore.release()
                print('Dealer: sold a car', flush=True)
            else:
                print('Dealer: waiting for a client', flush=True)
                sleep(1)


def main():
    s = Semaphore(10)
    f = Factory(20, s)
    d = Dealership(s)

    f.start()
    d.start()

    f.join()
    d.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

It does what was asked and nothing more, except that it imports `randint()` and `sleep()` to simulate waiting for clients willing to buy cars.

- the factory is initialised with the number of cars it needs to produce and the semaphore; in a nicer implementation, where there might be more dealers, you might need a more complicated setup, but this assumes 1 dealership and 1 factory.
- once running, as long as the factory needs to produce a car, it tries to acquire the semaphore, which will only succeed if there's room, otherwise it will wait until it does acquire it (i.e. when there is space at the dealership); every time it acquires it, it produces and delivers a car and reports this on the screen, only to try again immediately, until done.
- the dealership is initialised with the same semaphore
- once running, it checks if there are clients (coinflip) and if there are none, it waits for 1 second and then checks again; if there is a client, it signals a release of the semaphore

This is the simplest solution, but it has plenty of issues left:

- it's not using a `BoundedSemaphore`, so the dealer can sell a car even if it has none
- the dealership keeps running forever, selling non-existent cars because there is no condition to stop

But I think it addresses the core problem you were having: how to use a semaphore to make sure the factory doesn't overproduce.

If you run into more specific problems getting it to work perfectly, you should probably post a working solution and ask a focused question about a specific problem.